# Why MLE is not biased in presence of incomplete data when parameters distinctness does not hold?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, missing-data

When estimating MLE in presence of missing data, the missing data process can be ignored if the data are MAR and parameters distinctness assumption (generating vs missing data processes) does hold.

I know that when the parameters distinctness is not met (but MAR respected), the estimation based on the observed-data likelihood (instead of the full likelihood) are valid but not fully efficient. How can we prove that?

Comment: What leads you to believe MLE is unbiased in the complete-data case?  Sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't!

Comment: @jbowman Thanks for your answer. I perfectly know that MLE can be biased. I tried to rephrase my question.